# Javascript function does not complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am writing a JavaScript function to close a fancybox on the submission of the form located in the fancybox. Here it is:

```
function closeFancyBox() {
    $.fancybox.close();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
}
```

It's triggered in this way inside the fancybox:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    parent.closeFancyBox();    
});
```

Here's the thing: the fancybox is closing correctly, but fullcalendar is not refreshing the display. When I call `closeFancyBox();` from the console, though, it works and fullCalendar refreshes. I'm stumped here.

EDIT:

Per danronmoon's suggestion, I added a breakpoint after the `$.fancybox.close();` call and checked what `$('#calendar')` returned... it returned a div element, as expected.

Comment: why are you calling the function through a variable property? `parent.closeFancyBox();` shouldnt be `closeFancyBox();`?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint and seeing what $("#calendar") returns

Comment: calling parent.closeFancyBox(); because the call is taking place within an iframe located on that page

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting the form so obviously it will redirect to another page so unless you stop the redirect from happening you will not see all your code work.

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    parent.closeFancyBox();
    // run either of the following.
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This seems to prevent the form from submitting (i.e. the data being saved to the database).

Comment: yes, so are you trying to show your calendar before submiting the form? it will disappear anyway.

Comment: Here's how it works: Calendar fetches events and is displayed. Clicking on a date on the calendar opens a fancybox, inside is an iframe that has a form on it, which saves to the database of events. After the form is submitted, the fancybox should close and the calendar should refresh with the event just added via the form present.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what caused this, but I did manage to 'fix' it by moving the call to fullCalendar's `refetchEvents` to the fancybox `afterClose` hook.

So in short, this fixed the symptoms, but I don't know what was causing the underlying problem.